# Jmeter+influxdb when you create a table, but there is no data in the table

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

After executing the test plan for JMeter, the influxdb generates a table, but there is no data in the table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the backend listener config. How long were you running the test?

Comment: backend listener config  has been added;  10 threads/ 1 second,   A total of one second

Comment: I would advise you to run the test for atleast a min to see if the data is getting created. Jmetet is able to create the tables properly. It can insert data too. If it still does not work, what error you see in the log?

Comment: My influxdb still can not find the data (from * jmeter.11.a.count "select"), but I can read the grafana inside the data;

In addition, the problem of my newly uploaded pictures can be answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow the syntax of your query example `from * jmeter.11.a.count "select"`, but your measurement names have periods in them, which requires that they be surrounded by double-quotes when querying. Make sure you are submitting a query of the form `SELECT * FROM "jmeter.11.a.count"`

Comment: This is my fault, I query using SELECT * FROM "jmeter.11.a.count", which is just the wrong comments,I feel sorry for that.

Comment: So you are saying that `SELECT * FROM "jmeter.11.a.count"` returns no data when run from the CLI or from `curl`? What is the output from `SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "jmeter.11.a.count"`

Comment: I repeat my question, I can read through the influxdb to the grafana data, but I do not directly use the influxdb query data show

Comment: CatBig, I'm having trouble understanding your exact meaning. Are you saying that querying InfluxDB directly returns results, but Grafana isn't showing the data as you expect? You say things like " 
My influxdb still can not find the data" and "influxdb generates a table, but there is no data in the table" but those are very vague descriptions and have no technical precision. Please give actual input/output from your attempts to query so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I use JMeter test plan execution, in influxdb generated table, as shown in figure a, and can be read to data by monitoring tools (grafana), but I directly inside the influxdb execution of queries, there is no data

Comment: Again, CatBig, you are asserting that there is no data, but you don't say how you are executing the queries or give any example output. `SHOW MEASUREMENTS` is not a query that returns individual points. It is the equivalent of "SHOW TABLES" in a traditional RDBMS. You must execute a `SELECT` query to return actual metrics data. Please show `SELECT` queries submitted to InfluxDB via `curl` or the CLI to demonstrate the data issues.

Comment: I uploaded a new picture in the problem, the trouble to help me to see

Comment: The Admin UI has issues displaying very large result sets, due to browser challenges. Can you try issuing this command: `curl -Gi 'http://localhost/query?pretty=true' --data-urlencode "db=jmeter" --data-urlencode "q=SELECT * FROM \"jmeter.11.a.count\""

Answer (score 0):

When you do a show measurements, you get a list of measurements which Jmeter is capturing while running the test.

If you want to see the measurements captured, you need to run a query something like

Select * from "

From your screenshots,

Show Measurements, returns values like

Jmeter.all.a.count
jmeter.all.a.max.

so, you need to run a query something like

select * from "Jmeter.all.a.count"  and this would certainly provide you with results.

I am not sure why you are running a query like

select * from "jmeter.ll.a.count"

Since there is no such measurement, if would run a successful query, but would not find any results.